# Is there a way of shallow render a react component that uses a react-apollo query

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-apollo

This is the component that i want to test. And i want to use shallow render for this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import MY_QUERY from './MyQuery.graphql';
import Component from './Component';

const Container = () => (
    <Query query={MY_QUERY}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (loading) return null;
        if (error) return null;

        return <Component data={data} />;
      }}
    </Query>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shallow()` + [`renderProp()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/renderProp.html) will do the job:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Container />).find(Query);
const result = wrapper.renderProp('children')({ loading: false, data: someMockedData });
expect(result.find(Component).prop('data')).toEqual(someMockedData);
```

Comment: Thanks, i only needed to change the first line to dive in, and it worked

```shallow(<Container />).dive();```